# How to store data into object then into arraylist

Tags: java, sql, mysqli

At the moment i am trying to retrieve data from the database and then store it into an object. i am trying to retrieve 1 by 1 and store it into an object which will be stored into an arraylist. Below is my code that i have tried.

```
 import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import eldertrack.db.SQLObject;

public class DosageData{
private static String elderName;
private static int elderAge;
private static String elderGender;


public DosageData(){

}

public DosageData(String elderName, int elderAge, String elderGender) {
    this.elderName = elderName;
    this.elderAge = elderAge;
    this.elderGender = elderGender;

}

public String getElderName() {
    return elderName;
}

public void setElderName(String elderName) {
    this.elderName = elderName;
}

public int getElderAge() {
    return elderAge;
}

public void setElderAge(int elderAge) {
    this.elderAge = elderAge;
}

public String getElderGender() {
    return elderGender;
}

public void setElderGender(String elderGender) {
    this.elderGender = elderGender;
}
public void print(){
    System.out.println("Name: "+getElderName());
    System.out.println("Age: "+getElderAge());
    System.out.println("Gender: "+getElderGender());
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    SQLObject so = new SQLObject();
    ResultSet rs=so.getResultSet("SELECT * FROM et_elderly");
    ArrayList<DosageData> DosageList=new ArrayList<DosageData>();
    DosageData data=new DosageData();
    try {
        while(rs.next()){
        data.setElderName(rs.getString("name"));
        data.setElderAge(10);
        data.setElderGender(rs.getString("gender"));

        }
    } catch (SQLException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    DosageList.add(data);
    for(int i=0;i<DosageList.size();i++){
    DosageList.get(i).print();
}
}

}
```

Comment: Need to ask for help with a problem. It's not clear what, if any, problem you are having.

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get an error? If so, where is the stack trace? If not, do you get results you don't expect? Please add the data and the results you expect vs. the results you got.

Comment: At the moment when i run this code it just retrieves and store the first row of data into the object. Which means to say it is stuck at the first row of data and it does not seem to be advancing to the next row, Hence when i run this code it prints out 5 times of the same row of data. (Since i have 5 rows of different data)

Comment: Please indent code sensibly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove static from your fields - you are overriding those values with each new Dataset from DB

```
 public class DosageData{
    private /*static*/ String elderName;
    private /*static*/ int elderAge;
    private /*static*/ String elderGender;
...
```